# Записать в куки клик по кнопке?

Tags: cookie

Подскажите пожалуйста, на сайте есть версия для слабовидящих(изменения сделаны на js). Вопрос - как можно клик по этой ссылке записать в куки?

```js
 var currentText = $('#version-toggler').text();
$('#version-toggler').click(function(){
  $('html, body').toggleClass('vision');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).text('Включить обычную версию');
  } else {
    $(this).text(currentText);
  }
});
```

Jquery cookie подключается с яндекса..

Answer (score 0):

Собственно сам додумал...

```js
function setMyCookie() {
 
    myCookieVal = $('html, body').hasClass('vision') ? 'isActive' : 'notActive';
    $.cookie('myCookieName', myCookieVal, { path: '/' });    
}
 var currentText = $('#version-toggler').text();
if ($.cookie('myCookieName') == 'isActive') {
    $('html, body').addClass('vision');    
 $('#version-toggler').text('Включить обычную версию');
} else {
    $('html, body').removeClass('vision');
 $(this).text(currentText);
}

$("#version-toggler").click(function () {
    $('html, body').toggleClass('vision');
    setMyCookie();
});
```